# Displaying search bar in navigation bar in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

`UISearchDisplayController` had a `boolean` property called `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar`. What's the equivalent in iOS 8 to have my search bar move up there? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code, I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working. When I click the search bar, it just disappears instead of moving itself and the navigation bar up.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

var tableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self


    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar


    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    self.setupSearchBar()




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

}

func setupSearchBar() {

    // Set search bar position and dimensions
    var searchBarFrame: CGRect = self.searchController.searchBar.frame
    var viewFrame = self.view.frame
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchBarFrame.origin.x, searchBarFrame.origin.y + 64,viewFrame.size.width, 44)


    // Add search controller's search bar to our view and bring it to forefront
    self.view.addSubview(self.searchController.searchBar)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

According to Apple :

> `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that [`UISearchDisplayDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate) is also deprecated.) To manage the presentation of a search bar and display search results in iOS 8 and later, instead use [`UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/searchBar).
>
> The `UISearchController` class defines an interface that manages the presentation of a search bar in concert with the search results controller’s content. The search results controller, a `UIViewController` object specified by the [searchResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/searchResultsController) property, manages the results of the search.

Now you can use the `UISearchController` to show the search bar in your navigation bar in the following way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    
       self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
    
       self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
       self.searchController.delegate = self
       self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    
       self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
       self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    
       self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    
       self.definesPresentationContext = true        
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

But you have to consider you need to set a `UINavigationController` like in this Storyboard :

[image]

You can do it very easy  just select your `ViewController` and see the following steps:

[image]

And then you should see in your device when you make click in the search bar the following picture:

[image]

I hope this help you

Comment: That didn't really do it for me. I posted my code. Feel free to look at it and tell me why this isn't going the way I want it to.

Comment: @MihadAlzayat I tested it using a navigation bar and it works fine and don't dissapears, but what really you want? put a searchbar underneath the navigation bar (in the top of the tableview)?

Comment: @MihadAlzayat See updated answer to see how to do it using navigation bar as you asked

Comment: Thanks, that's extremey helpful. But what if I have a single view application that doesn't require a navigation controller, but I still want to have that bar at the top of the view? Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes of course you can put you searchbar in your case in the heder of you tableview too if you want

Comment: Also, one last thing! What is acting as my searchResultsController when it is being set to nil? Do I need to create a separate UITableViewController to display the search results in the UITableViewController's UITableView?

Comment: Yes your searchbar is separate from you tableviewcontroller, there a lot of tutorials to know how to do it , it's not difficult.

Comment: @VictorSigler While showing search bar in navigation bar its takes lot of left padding because of "<" back button frame doesn't look nice, How to deal with that? I want to achieve someting like twitter app where the spacing between back button and Search bar is not much

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that when you click in the search bar, it presents a new view controller behind the search bar and keyboard, rather than just the dimmed version of the view controller the search bar is attached to?

Comment: Hello, this is working very weel but, how can a I close or hide the searbar? Any idea?

Comment: the line: self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar is work just fine to me. Here all my code:                                     let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)               searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

Comment: its working but on click on search for searching then search bar changes its position