# displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar deprecated in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I'm trying to find an alternative to displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar for iOs8, is there anything I can use (in swift)?

I tried `self.navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController.searchBar` but it doesn't do anything.

I don't understand how to find the replacement for functions that are deprecated, on the apple documentation it just say deprecated with no alternative, if you have any tips it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try UISearchBar: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UISearchBarStyle

Comment: I've been there, I don't see anything replacing displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar

Comment: @KaliAney I post an answer about it in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226835/displaying-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-in-ios-8/30227166#30227166

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VictorSigler, the only problem is I don't use a navigationController and cannot use it there because it messes up with other parts of my code, any other way to do it without it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put an `UISearchBar` in a `UINavigationBar` without using a `UINavigationController` without problem, but you have to do a minor change only, first you need to define an `@IBOutlet` to the `UINavigationItem` inside your `UINavigationBar` but its name need to be different from the `navigationItem` property defined in all the `UIViewController` class, see the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationItemBar: UINavigationItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

       self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
       self.searchController.delegate = self
       self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

       self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
       self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

       self.navigationItemBar.titleView = searchController.searchBar

       self.definesPresentationContext = true        
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And then you can see something like this in your simulator:

[image]

I hope this help you.

Comment: I try exactly this on iOS 10 but In the end I have a search bar in my navigation item that does not become first responder.