# iOS Search Bar in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm currently developing an application that has a MapView as the main view. I want to have a search button in the navigation bar that brings up a search bar within the same navigation bar.

If you've used the Twitter app you'll know what I'm talking about.

[image: Search prompt button]

[image: After search button is pressed (excuse the 'McWhopper')]

I've seen a ton of guides and tutorials that show how to implement something similar to this in a table view however this isn't what I want to do.

Can anyone tell me what the best way to do this would be?

As somebody answered *very* quickly pointed out - my question looks very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095477/uisearchbar-in-navigationbar) question. However nothing on that question seemed to work for me and it doesn't address the issue of getting the search bar to appear on a button press.

As it is right now my search doesn't need a `SearchViewController` as all it does is use an `MKLocalSearch` to position the `MapView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all , you need to know that what Twitter does is present a new `UIViewController` when the search button is tapped , but without animation. In this new `UIViewController` you can put your `UISearchBar` in code like in the answer you put in your question or using Interface Builder, it's up to you.

See my answer of this here [Displaying search bar in navigation bar in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226835/displaying-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-in-ios-8/30227166#30227166)

If want you want to do is present the `UISearchBar` in the same `UIViewController` where the search icon appears, the you need to handle an `@IBAction` for the `UIBarButtonItem` and the change it according your needs (with animation if you want).

I strongly recommend the way of Twitter does, is more cleanest.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you an idea i tried myself and it is working but i can't provide you a code right now

I'm sure you can find the code easily of what i am gonna tell you.

first you have to know that in the navigation controller the title is in UIView that you can access so all you need to do is

create a UIView and in the navigationItem.tittleView assign your view to it like this `navigationItem.tittleView = the created view`

this create a search bar object and add it the created view as subview

```
view.addSubView(the search bar view object)
```

hope this is what you are looking for .... good luck