# Embed Search bar controller in navbar

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking to create something similar to this, where there is a search bar in the Navigation bar. The photo below displays what I currently have in my storyboard. I would like for it to look something like the photo below that, without the customizations to the UI. I have tried placing the search bar below the navigation bar but it takes up more space that I would like and looks cluttered and unprofessional, can anybody help me here? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several links on SO explaining how to do this already. Check out the following: [UISearchBar in navigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095477/uisearchbar-in-navigationbar), [Displaying search bar in navigation bar in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226835/displaying-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-in-ios-8). If neither of those seem to work for your situation explain 1) What method you tried and 2) Why it's not working. You may even add some of your sample code to show how you are attempting to integrate a solution and that it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should add tableview and search bar programmatically. By doing so, search bar does not scroll while your tableview scrolls up and down.